# The condition of my PHP/PDO code does not repeat

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I want to create an activated or deactivated user status on a platform, to do this if "Activation" is '0' it must be updated to become '1' and the user status becomes active while if "Activation" is '1' it must be updated to become '0' and the user status becomes inactive. Unfortunately this formula does not work continuously, what is the problem?

```
<?php

$mysqlDsn = 'mysql: host=localhost; dbname=dbClient';



$activation = "UPDATE Clients_data
SET activation=1
WHERE name='Frank Lin';";

$deactivation = "UPDATE Clients_data
SET activation=0
WHERE name='Frank Lin';";



try {

    $pdo = new PDO($mysqlDsn, $db_password ='root', $db_user ='root');


 $testActivation = ("SELECT activation from Clients_data where name = 'Frank Lin';");
 $user = $pdo -> query ($testActivation);
 

 if ($user == 0){

    echo ‘yes’;
    $pdo ->query($activation);

 }

 else {
       echo 'no';
        $pdo ->query($deactivation);
    }
 }


catch(PDOException $e) {

    echo "rpr". $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

Comment: so you want to toggle it, add in a [case statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) in part of an update `UPDATE Clients_data SET activation = (CASE WHEN activation = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) WHERE name = ?` don't need to first select

Comment: `if ($user == 0)` is wrong, that variable holds the result of PDO::query, which is a PDOStatement instance - not the individual column value that you are trying to access.

Comment: If you're just flipping a flag you can simply do `UPDATE Clients_data SET activation = 1 - activation WHERE name = 'Frank Lin'`. You don't need to know what the value was beforehand. Also remove your `;` at the end of the statement, it's unneeded and will cause errors.